# Monorepo - sharing component between React and Preact app

Tags: reactjs, vite, monorepo, preact

I have a monorepo using pnpm which contains a React app (bundled with vite).

I have a new project where I want to keep the bundle low, so I thought of using Preact (vite).

The idea would be, in the monorepo, to create a components' library (in Preact or React), and to be able to use those components in my React and also in my Preact app.

I cannot figure how to do it, I thought that using `preact/compat` would be sufficient, but it does not work (error: cannot read property undefined of current) when trying to import a component.

Do you have any ideas ?

Maybe they are better ideas/solutions for my problem here.

Comment: You need to provide way more information for anyone to meaningfully help you with the error. At a high level, you can indeed use React components in Preact w/ `preact/compat`.

Comment: First, the post was more to take ideas about the concept of sharing components between React and Preact in a monorepo, to know if it's something possible and if someone already tried that. 
If it's supposed to work, I'll indeed share more information about my case, thanks

Comment: For better or for worse, StackOverflow isn't a place "to take ideas about the concept...", that's specifically against the question guidelines (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). But yes, it's absolutely possible to have React and Preact components in a monorepo, there's nothing there that would inherently cause issues.